# get useful text representation in debugger for external class (of which i cannot modify the code)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-debugging

I am programming something with the help of an API. This API has a class `Component2` with a not very useful override of `ToString`. Because of that, debugging isn't very comfortable - see screenshot:

[image]

The class has a getter property `Name` which gives me the information I need.

**How can I make Visual Studio to output the `Name` value instead of `ToString()`?**

I am using Visual Studio 2015.

---

To clarify:

This is the current situation:

[image]

And this is what I want it to be:

[image]

---

Enabling native debugging or replacing my one line of code with

```
dynamic swxRootComp = _activeDoc.ConfigurationManager.ActiveConfiguration.GetRootComponent3(false);
var nameValue = swxRootComp.Name;
```

allows me to see more than before, but the `Name` is still nowhere to be found:

[image]

Comment: Can you access the API?

Comment: What do you mean by "access"? I can use it of course, but neither see nor modify the code.

Comment: Seems to be a wrapper over native code. Have you tried to enable native debugging?

Comment: Why do you think, there should be a `Name` Getter on the Object? There is no such a getter. Also `IComponent2` is **Interface** not a class.

Comment: is this the solidworks api from siemens?

Comment: It is a COM interface pointer, nothing to do with ToString().  Only the author of the COM component can help you out, use a telephone and tell him you want him to implement IDispatch::GetTypeInfo().  That will very likely be a "no", but you can't get a "yes" unless you try.

Comment: I thought the usual behaviour of the debugger is to call the method `ToString()` whenever I do a mouseover. And I thought I could tell VisualStudio to use a method of my choice instead of `ToString()` for that case. Since I can call `swxRootComp.Name` in code, I expected the debugger to be able to do the same. It seems that my assumption is wrong. But can anyone explain why? What is so special about a COM object? I can use it as a normal class/interface, so why can't the debugger?

Comment: @Smartis 1. I don't understand why you say that there is no `Name` getter on the object. I can call it, so it must be there, right? 2. You are right, `IComponent2` is an interface. But I don't see that it matters, since the object I get (`_activeDoc.ConfigurationManager....`) is an instance of some class. But I changed everything from `IComponent2` to `Component2` (which is part of the API as well) to prevent further confusion. It doesn't change anything in the behaviour of the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

use `component2.GetType().Name` for the component object

Answer (score 0):

Press Alt+Enter (in Visual Studio), go to the "Debugging" Tab and Enable "Native Code Debugging".

Answer (score 0):

For that purpose, you can use the [DebuggerDisplayAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228992(v=vs.110).aspx).
For example

```
[DebuggerDisplay("{value}", Name = "{key}")]
public class KeyValuePairs
{
   private object key;
   private object value;

   public KeyValuePairs(object key, object value)
   {
       this.value = value;
       this.key = key;
   }
}
```

Comment: But how do I use it in my context? I cannot modify the code of the `IComponent2` class...

Comment: Technically you just said *without overriding `ToString()`*. This post is a valid answer to that question (although not helpful in your case I guess). @Kjara

Comment: Not any more. Changed title of the question.